# jQuery Deferred continue to resolve after fail handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have a promise that can resolve or reject. I want to do something specific in those cases, and then continue resolving the promise chain (essentially I want to "catch" the rejected promise, do something, then continue resolving).

Here's a functional snippet that shows the issue I'm running into :

```js
var def = $.Deferred();
def.then(
  function() {
    console.log('first success handler');
  },
  function() {
    console.log('first fail handler');
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
  }
);
def.then(
  function() {
    console.log('second success handler');
  },
  function() {
    console.log('second fail handler');
  }
);
def.done(function() {
  console.log('done handler');
});

def.reject();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Expected result :

```
first fail handler
second success handler
done handler
```

Current result :

```
first fail handler
second fail handler
```

According to jQuery docs :

> As of jQuery 1.8, the deferred.then() method returns a new promise
>   that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a
>   function[...].  These filter functions can return a new value to be
>   passed along to the promise's .done() or .fail() callbacks, or they
>   can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which
>   will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's
>   callbacks.

So I have no idea why this is not working. I expected the returned resolved promise in the first fail handler to allow the rest of the promise chain to continue resolving.

Comment: This is a known bug. See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962655/recovering-from-rejected-promises-in-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern ...

```
var def = $.Deferred();
def.then(successHandler, errorHandler);
def.then(successHandler, errorHandler);
// etc.
```

... forms two (or more) branches, each `then()` being dependent only on `def`. Each branch possesses independent filtering power, but it is not exploited.

That is very different from ...

```
var def = $.Deferred();
def.then(successHandler, errorHandler).then(successHandler, errorHandler);  // etc.
```

... which forms a single chain (without branching). The first `then()` is dependent on `def`, and the second `then()` dependent on the first `then()`. Here, the filtering power of the first `then()` *is* exploited by chaining another `then()` (and so on).

Therefore, you will get the expected output by converting the code in the question to the second pattern :

```
var def = $.Deferred();

def.then(function() {
    console.log('first success handler');
}, function() {
    console.log('first fail handler'); // (1)
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
}).then(function() {
    console.log('second success handler'); // (2)
}, function() {
    console.log('second fail handler');
}).done(function() {
    console.log('done handler'); // (3)
});

def.reject();
```

In a nutshell, that's what promise chaining is all about.

But don't forget about branching completely. In certain circumstances, it is essential. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703794/3478010) for example, `batchRequests()` returns `_p`, which can be further chained by the caller (that's one branch), but also forms its own private branch with `_p.then(..., ...)`. Don't worry if you can't follow it completely - it's fairly complicated - for now trust me that branching is an essential part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the docs is

> the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise

You were however throwing away that return value, and did invoke the next `.then(…)` on the original `def`.

You will want to use

```
var p = $.Deferred().reject().promise();

p.then(function() {
    console.log('first success handler');
}, function() {
    console.log('first fail handler');
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
}).then(function() {
//^^^^^ chain directly on the result
    console.log('second success handler');
}, function() {
    console.log('second fail handler');
}).then(function() {
//^^^^^
  console.log('done handler');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code is effectively doing is queuing two handlers (through the `then` functions). When the deferred is rejected it can no longer be altered.

When the Deferred is rejected, the first `then` handler fires writing your first console message.

The line `return $.Deferred().resolve();` will create a new resolved Deferred but it is not "return"ed to your second `then` since that handler is already tied to the first Deferred instance.

Consequently, your second `then` handler will now fire also hitting the failFilter (the handler for when the Deferred is rejected).

One approach you could take is to pass a value when you reject (or resolve) your Deferred. You can then receive that response and take remedial action as shown in this (somewhat contrived) sample:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test"></div>

<script>
    var def = $.Deferred();
    def.then(
            function () {
                console.log('first success handler');
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log('first fail handler');
                console.log(response);
            }
    );
    def.then(
            function () {
                console.log('second success handler');
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response === 999) {
                    // do something to recover from earlier reject
                    console.log('recovery action initiated');
                } else {
                    console.log('second fail handler');
                }
            }
    );
    def.done(function () {
        console.log('done handler');
    });

    def.reject(999);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I know of no way to interject between the two `then` handlers, they are simply two queued handlers to the same Deferred.

Comment: Right, I understand what you are getting at, but the docs very clearly say about the success / fail filters that _"they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks."_ . So what I want to know is why the code is not acting like the docs say it should.

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are getting that information.