# Cache a value fetched from a listener callback

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

> NOTE: [Caching JavaScript promise results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709987/caching-javascript-promise-results) does not apply because that question doesn't involve an API that calls the listener callback on state mutation (which means the API stores the listener function and may call it multiple times, whenever  its state gets updated).

I have a state object type `State`.

Now I have an API `API.addEventListener()`, which accepts a listener of type `function(!State):undefined`, and a boolean `repeating`. If called, this API will store the listener callback, and call it with a `State` object if

- a `State` becomes available (nonexistence to existence)
- a new `State` object becomes available (mutation), if `repeating` is true.

Originally, whenever I call `doStuff()` to perform my logic, I will call `API.addEventListener()` to fetch the most recent `State` object:

```js
/**
 * @return {!Promise{!State}}
 */
function getStatePromise() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    API.addEventListener(resolve, /* repeating */ false);
  });
}

function doStuff() {
  getStatePromise().then(state => {
    // my logic
  });
}
```

`doStuff()` might be called multiple times at different points in my program.

Now, I'd like to cache the result retrieved from `API.getState()` in a persistent object in my JS script, and let the code update the cache when a new `State` becomes available. I don't want to change `doStuff()`, because it's fairly complicated. Is it possible to just change `getStatePromise()` to do this?

My current attempt is:

```js
let cacheStorage = {}; // or window.localStorage, but it's beside the point

/**
 * @return {!Promise{!State}}
 */
function getStatePromise() {
  if (cacheStorage.state !== undefined) {
    return Promise.resolve(cacheStorage.state);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    API.addEventListener(newState => {
        cacheStorage.state = newState;
        resolve(newState); // ??? what if the listener is called again?
    }, /* repeating */ true);
  });
}

function doStuff() {
  getStatePromise().then(state => {
    // my logic
  });
}
```

When `doStuff()` is called for the first time, `cacheStorage` is empty, so `getStatePromise()` will fetch the `State` object, populate the cache, and return a promise which resolves to the `State` object. Then, when `doStuff()` is called for the second time, it will just return a promise that resolves to the cached `State` object.

However, the problem is, when a new `State` becomes available later, `API` will call the listener callback again, which means `resolve()` will once again be called (see `???` in code). This doesn't sound right, because it is resolving a promise that is already resolved. How should I fix this?

**Edit: is it the fix?**

Replace

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
    API.addEventListener(newState => {
        cacheStorage.state = newState;
        resolve(newState); // ??? what if the listener is called again?
    }, /* repeating */ true);
  });
```

with

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
    let initialCall = true;
    API.addEventListener(newState => {
        cacheStorage.state = newState;
        if (initialCall) {
          resolve(newState);
          initialCall = false;
        }
    }, /* repeating */ true);
  });
```

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709987/caching-javascript-promise-results

Comment: Hey @MajiD yeah I read it before posting this. That question is not quite the same as my scenario, as that post doesn't worry about API calling the listener on state mutation. In my scenario, the API stores the listener, and may call it multiple times.